# How do I fill a texture with another texture?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I created a small tileable texture in blender. Now I need to fill a larger texture with the small texture.

[image]

I need to use the above texture on a large plane so it tiles.(like tiles) But when I use the fill brush it only fills a color, not the texture. How do I solve this?

Sorry if the question is not clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your question it looks to me as if you're trying to texture paint a repeating pattern onto another mesh. This is indeed possible, but not using the Fill Brush. You'll need to choose the Draw Brush for this instead. See this little example for the settings:

[image: Draw Settings]

When setting the Brush Mapping to **Stencil**, you will see an Overlay plane in the 3D Viewport as soon as you put the mouse cursor there. The Size parameter allows you to set a custom number of repeats for the texture itself. The result could look somewhat like this (Plane and Overlay visible at the same time):

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way how to blend textures is mix them together using *"Colors"* -> *"MixRGB"*  node in node editor:
[image]

Second option is use external image editor Like GIMP, Krita, Photoshop etc.
For fast and easy workflow you can set path to your image editor in

*"File: -> "User Preferences" -> "File" -> "Image editor"*

Now you can send your texture to your external image editor from Blender UV/Image editor by

*"Image" -> "Edit externaly"*.

If you finish editing in external Image editor, just overwrite original image and In Blender Image Editor use

*"ALT+R"* for reload your edited image.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help my problem. I want the large texture to contain many of the small texture. Like Tiles. Repeating to make a bigger texture.

Comment: In this case, look at mapping node - here you can set "scale" - For example scale 2 will repeat your texture 2 times. Or you can make UV coordinates bigger in UV/Image editor.

Comment: BTW: Your question is: "How do I fill a texture with another texture". I'ts misleading